# Where to store Connection String in Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string, appsettings

We can store Connection String in Web.config file in two ways
 One is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer"
          connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Other One is

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="ConnectionString"
       value="server=localhost;database=Northwind;uid=sa;password=secret;" />
</appSettings>
```

Now I want to know 

What is difference between these two approach?

Which one is better way?

What  are their limitations?

**UPDATE**:Can you explain that `<connectionString>` has any significant advantage over  `<appSetting>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [connectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) element would be the most appropriate way to handle connection strings. The appSettings element is how connection strings used to be handled before .NET 2.0. You can use either approach but it is probably easier to work with multiple connection strings if you use the connectionString element. With multiple connection strings stored in appSettings you would have to parse each name (or value) to work out if it is a connection string before you could use it. This leads to maintenance issues. It's easier to just check if all of the connectionString items are present.

Answer (score 13):

The [`connectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) section is *dedicated* to connection strings and was only introduced in .NET 2.0.

`appSettings` is more general and is to be used for other application settings.

You should use the `connectionStrings` section, as it can also be [encrypted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) separately from any other settings.

Comment: It also gives you a strongly typed connection string object via the WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings collection that you can play around with if you want to.

Answer (score 6):

The first approach can be accessed directly by some data controls like SQLDataSource.

Answer (score 2):

If you add your connection strings to the appSettings section, you need to manually retrieve them using the [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) method.

By adding your connection strings instead to the [connectionStrings element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx), .NET can automatically find these by name when you create your connection object.

Answer (score 1):

connection-string section is declare the connection for system.I mean that you application know that you string is connectionString. If you will use appSettings for application it is just any string value.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the benefits mentioned in the other answers, `connectionStrings` elements have a `providerName` attribute that `appSettings` elements do not. This is particularly useful if your data source is *not* SQL Server.